función para poner un texto dependiendo del contenido
Quiero rellenar una columna con unos datos dependiendo de lo que encuentre en el texto de otra,
¿Es posible? Ahora mismo estoy usando esta función:
=SI(CONTAR.SI(B2;"" & "sr.win32" & "")>0;"SERA";"")
y tengo estos datos:
0101sr.win32
0102kr.win32
al encontrar el texto "sr.win32." rellena con "SERA" la columna, quiero poner que si encuentra "kr.win32" rellene con "KORA" pero en una misma columna.
Gracias

Utiliza esta fórmula:
=SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("sr.win32"; A2)); "SERA";SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("kr.win32"; A2)); "KORA"; ""))

El texto a evaluar debe estar en la columna A.

Al final usé =BUSCARV(G3;Personajes!A:B;2;0) teniendo una hoja con los nombres a poner y lo que debía encontrar en el texto.
gracias
